# How to increase the size of an array on individual element clicks

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, tic-tac-toe

I've decided to get out of tutorial hell and challenge myself by making an X an O'S (tic-tac-toe) game by myself. As shown below. I have managed to make the functions that will display X and O on click. But now I need to enable the display of X and O to alternate on every click. I am trying to make an array whose length increases on every button click. If the array's length is even O is displayed, if array's length is odd, X is displayed. But the array's length is only 1 on every click. How do I get the array's size to actually increase on every click?

Also for some odd reason the X is not being displayed on every odd click. What could the problem be?

**JavaScript code:**

```
for (let num = 1; num <= 9; num++) {
  const text = document.querySelector("#box" + num + " h1");
  const box = document.querySelector("#box" + num);
  // let boxCounted = document.getElementsByClassName("square");

  //current click
  const xclick = function setToX() {
    text.innerHTML = "X";
  };

  //next click
  const oclick = function setToO() {
    text.innerHTML = "O";
  };

  let trackCounter = [];
  let clickcount = 0;
  
  box.onclick = () => {
    trackCounter.push(clickcount);
    console.log(trackCounter);

    if (trackCounter.length % 2 == 0) {
      box.onclick = oclick; //not carried out/working
      console.log("Even");
    } else if (trackCounter.length % 2 == 1) {
      box.onclick = xclick; //not carried out/working
      console.log("odd");
    } else {
      console.log("error");
    }
  };
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>TicTacToe</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <section id="xosection">
      <div id="xogrid">
        <div class="row">
          <div id="box1" class="square">
            <h1></h1>
          </div>
          <div id="box2" class="square">
            <h1></h1>
          </div>
          <div id="box3" class="square">
            <h1></h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div id="box4" class="square">
            <h1></h1>
          </div>
          <div id="box5" class="square">
            <h1></h1>
          </div>
          <div id="box6" class="square">
            <h1></h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div id="box7" class="square">
            <h1></h1>
          </div>
          <div id="box8" class="square">
            <h1></h1>
          </div>
          <div id="box9" class="square">
            <h1></h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <script src="index2.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is a link to some previous progress of the code on github:
[text](https://github.com/19992018/tictactoe-by-me)

As mentioned I tried using an array hoping its length would increase. But it does not.

I may have incorporated some poor coding practices- like using a for loop to name the variables? Please let me know if I have and show me the best practices kindly. But also show me how to work around my thought process. Thank you so much in advance

Edit: I have deleted a variable called loopCount. It was there when I first asked the question.

Comment: You're doing everything in a `for()` loop that happens 9 times. That means you're setting the event handlers 9 times. Are you sure you want to do that?

Comment: @kmoser My intention was to use the for loop to just be able to manipulate all the 9 buttons and 9 h1's in the html.  However I cannot access the consts of the 9 buttons ( named box) and 9 h1's(named text) outside  the for loop; that is why I did everything inside the for loop.    What is the best way to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to make trackcounter array global or outside loop so your loop will be updated in every for loop iteration

```js
var trackCounter = [];
for (let num = 1; num <= 9; num++) {
  const text = document.querySelector("#box" + num + " h1");
  const box = document.querySelector("#box" + num);
  // let boxCounted = document.getElementsByClassName("square");

  //current click
  const xclick = function setToX() {
    text.innerHTML = "X";
  };

  //next click
  const oclick = function setToO() {
    text.innerHTML = "O";
  };

  //let trackCounter = [];
  let clickcount = 0;
  
  box.onclick = () => {
    trackCounter.push(clickcount);
    console.log(trackCounter);

    if (trackCounter.length % 2 == 0) {
      box.onclick = oclick; //not carried out/working
      console.log("Even");
    } else if (trackCounter.length % 2 == 1) {
      box.onclick = xclick; //not carried out/working
      console.log("odd");
    } else {
      console.log("error");
      console.log(countResult);
    }
  };
}
```

Try it, Hopefully it will resolve your problem

Comment: The loop works exactly how I wanted it to work. Thank you so much. However the display of X or O  only happens AFTER 9 button clicks. How can I resolve this. Or should I abandon the for loop as a whole. Is there a way I can resolve the issue stated in this comment?

Comment: use if condition outside loop in which check num or number of clicks exceeded from 9 then show it

Answer (score 0):

You can add event listener to the squares and maintain counter outside to determine what you need to print inside the square.
Here same logic of even's and odd's are applied.

```
const squares = document.querySelectorAll('.square');
const squareContainer = document.querySelector('#xogrid');
let count = 0;

squareContainer.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const target = e.target;
  if (target.classList.contains('square')) {
    if (count > squares.length - 1 || target.classList.contains('checked')) return;

    const displayElem = target.querySelector('h1');
    displayElem.innerText = count % 2 ? 'x' : 'o';
    target.classList.add('checked');
    count++;
  }
});
```